# pdo query only works the first time

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, connection

I have searched and searched, but can't find what I'm doing wrong, so here's my first StackOverflow question.

I am attempting to make a query to my entity table to get information about my entity, including the id for the corresponding address on the address table, but I can only make one query. The second query gives the error "No database selected". For testing, I have tried using the *exact same function* twice to make sure it's not a syntax error and this is the result I get:

name:Wolf, Dmitri

second try to same query:

No database selected

from this code:

```
$entity_id=1;
$row = getEntityById($entity_id);
echo "<p>name:" . $row['entity_name'] . "</p>";

echo "<p>second try to same query:</p>";
$row = getEntityById($entity_id);
echo "<p>name:" . $row['entity_name'] . "</p>";

function dbConnect ()
{
    require_once ('dogs.php');
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pwd);
        return $conn;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}

function getEntityById ($id)
{
    unset($conn);
    $conn=dbConnect();
    $sql = "select * from entity where id = $id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $error = $conn->errorInfo();
    if (isset($error[2])) die($error[2]);

    $numRows = $result->fetchColumn();
    $result->closeCursor();

    $theRow = null;
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        $theRow = $row;
    }

    return $theRow;
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Close Cursor doesn't seem to help.
Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I think this can be due to an exception.. debug the exception thrown.. just output the $e stack trace and confirm if you have exception if you try to connect to db again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmitri, Just change require_once ('dogs.php'); to require ('dogs.php');

The problem is that you requires the dogs.php file everytime you call the function, however ,as you might know, require_once only calls a file once per execution time. Just change it and should work fine.

Cheers,

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you, medina!